# Build two dictionaries based on a sorted list

Tags: python

What I want is get two dictionaries based on a sorted list

The form of input list is `(string, id)`. Example: `[("car", 1), ("car", 2), ("car", 2), ("book", 1), ("banana", 3)]`

The form of first output dictionary is `(id, term_frequency)`. Example: `{"car": [(1, 1), (2, 2)], "book": [(1, 1)], "banana": [(3, 1)]}`

The form of second output dictionary is the unique term frequency. Example: `{"car": 2, "book": 1, "banana": 1}` as there are two unique terms of car, car 1 and car 2

However, I only finished part of the code and can't continue, I can't get the logical stright. As the comment described, I do have a problem on update the dictionary. It seems that I should keep iterating through the list and check the conditions, maybe an if loop?

I wonder how should I keep working from my current code.

```
input_list = [("car", 1), ("car", 2), ("car", 2), ("book", 1), ("banana", 3)]
def get_index(list)
    index = {}
    doc_freq = {}
    
    index = 0
    
    while(index < len(list)):
        (term, doc_id) = list[index]
        index[term] = [(doc_id, 1)]
    #here is where I can't continue
    
    for(term, value) in index.items():
        doc_freq[term] = len(value)
        

    return index, doc_freq
```

Comment: Why do you use different data examples between your first example, second example, and code? And what does "I can't continue" mean? Like you're iterating through the list, you don't know how to keep updating your dictionary? Also, don't name your variable `list`, you just shadowed python's `list` built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of the data already being sorted:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as ig

input_list = [("car", 1), ("car", 2), ("car", 2), ("book", 1), ("banana", 3)]

d1 = {k: [(v, len(vs))
          for v, [*vs] in groupby(map(ig(1), g))]
      for k, g in groupby(input_list, ig(0))}

d2 = {k: len(v) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` is the easiest way to count up occurrences of a given thing in a list.  For example:

```
>>> item_ids = [("car", 1), ("car", 2), ("car", 2), ("book", 1), ("banana", 3)]
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> counter = Counter(item_ids)
>>> term_freq = defaultdict(list)
>>> for (item, num), count in counter.items():
...     term_freq[item].append((num, count))
...
>>> term_freq
{'car': [(1, 1), (2, 2)], 'book': [(1, 1)], 'banana': [(3, 1)]}
>>> unique_terms = dict(Counter(item for item, num in counter))
>>> unique_terms
{'car': 2, 'book': 1, 'banana': 1}
```

Comment: Sorry, was on mobile so I didn't see your identical answer. I guess this is a win for the pythonic idea that there should be one obvious way to do it

Comment: Hmm, why does the repr of `term_freq` not show that it's a defaultdict?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different format to having a tuple of `(id, frequency)`, however you can use default dicts to get a nice clean result:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l =  [("car", 1), ("car", 2), ("car", 2), ("book", 1), ("banana", 3)]

def get_index(input_list):
    result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for k, v in l:
        result[k][v] += 1
    return {k: dict(v) for k, v in result.items()}  # Converts the default dict back to a normal dict, if required.

print(get_index(l))

output:
{'car': {1: 1, 2: 2}, 'book': {1: 1}, 'banana': {3: 1}}
```

However this will also let you look up ids faster as you can do:

```
result[car][car_id]
```